# Binary trees contained of other binary trees

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I have a function that is supposed to tell whether a given binary tree A is contained by a given binary tree B. The function defines "contained" as "A is covered by B, or any complete subtree of B." If, for instance, tree A is an empty tree and tree B is not, would A therefore be contained in B? What about if they're both empty?

Thanks!

Comment: depends on how you define a valid binary tree. If this is an assignment (which it sounds like) clarify it with your teacher.

Comment: In the spec it says

A well-formed tree is either:
the empty tree or   an integer element with two well-formed trees as "children", a left "subtree" and a right subtree.

Answer (score 3):

In mathematic sense empty set (tree is just specialization of set) is contained in every other set including other empty set.

So yes on both your questions.

Empty set has even its wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set

[image]

---

Anyway it will become obvious from your implementation that the empty tree is contained in every other tree, an example implementation will look like this:

```
bool Tree::contains(const Tree& otherTree)
{
   for (n: otherTree)
   {
      if (!contains(n)) 
         return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Of course I can imagine better implementation especially when trees are sorted - but the point is that if `for(n: otherTree)` will cause no iterations then the result is true.